# Update GUI in mid-process (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a `ListBox` which shows images in a directory (binded to a list). In a method, i delete image from listbox, update it's source then delete image from the directory.

```
Test.questions.RemoveAt(index);
lstQuestions.ItemsSource=null;
lstQuestions.ItemsSource=Test.questions;
File.Delete(itemPath);
```

But because the GUI only updates after method is finished, the image is still shown when program tries to delete it so deletion fails.

I saw a few questions on stackoverflow about `Background Worker` and `Dispatcher` but no one gave even an example and i couldn't find anything useful about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the ListBox to an ObservableCollection, save the itemPath to a new variable before the Remove, Remove, and then delete the itemPath async / await.